# Converting an equation from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, volume

This is going to seem pretty basic, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a problem in my homework's text or if it's just not clicking for me.

I have to find the volume for the paraboloid $$z = 6 - x^2 - y^2$$

Now the homework problem states: "Before answering the problem, convince yourself that the equation of the paraboloid in cylindrical coordinates is $$z = 6 - r$$

This is where I'm at a loss. I am confident in evaluating the volume integral but I cannot convince myself that z = 6 - r.

Tell me if I'm doing this right or not:

$$ z = 6 - x^2 - y^2 $$ Where: $$ x = r \cos\theta $$ $$y = r \sin\theta$$
Then: $$ z = 6-(r^2(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta)) = 6-r^2 $$ $$ z = 6 - r^2$$

Is that not correct?

Comment: That is a typo. You are correct. $z=6-r^2$

Comment: Yes, it should be $z=6-r^2$, and you could also use $x^2+y^2=r^2$ to get this.

Comment: Thanks guys. That was driving me crazy for a bit. It really was the wording that kept me doubting: "convince yourself."